# Why is my password generator only generating one password?

Tags: python

Im a beginner to python and wish for help with this

```
print('Password generator ')
letter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*().,?0123456789'
numv = int(input('Amounts of Passwords to generate:'))
leny = input('Input your password length:')
leny = int(leny)
print('Here are your passwords:')
for pwd in range(numv):
    passwords = ''
for c in range(leny):
    passwords += random.choice(letter)
print(passwords)
```

I don't understand why it isn't printing out more than one password when I run it.

Comment: If that's your actual indentation, then the last 3 lines must be indented under the previous line

Comment: Your first loop doesn't do anything, and that's why you get only one password. As @Martheen has pointed out, you need to indent the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is nest the second for-loop in the first one.

```py
for pwd in range(numv):
    passwords = ''
```

This for-loop doesn't do anything as of right now it is equivalent as if you had just written:

```py
passwords = ''
```

To achieve the desired behaviour you'd need to do something like this:

```py
passwords = ''
for pwd in range(numv):
    for c in range(leny):
        passwords += random.choice(letter)
    passwords += "|" # This is just a separator
```

You'll notice I added `passwords += "|"` at the end of every iteration of the outer for-loop. This is just for you to be able to distinguish the different passwords when you print the string later. Without it the output would look like `password1password2password3` but with it you'd get `password1|password2|password3`

An even better approach is to declare `passwords` as a list and append the different passwords to that list:

```py
passwords = []
for pwd in range(numv):
    password = ""
    for c in range(leny):
        password += random.choice(letter)
    passwords.append(password)

for password in passwords:
    print(password)
```

Comment: Import random..This code will work